# Migration does not create the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, migration

I run normal migration and it normally creates migration, only it does not create the database. On another computer he created usually using the same settings, only on the one that is not giving. only the file in the migration folder. I've tried everything practically, if anyone knows how to answer I'll be grateful.
asp.net core MVC and visual studio.

Context class:

```
  public class ProjectContext : DbContext
  {
  public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectContext> options)
  : base(options)
```

{
}

```
   (appsettings.json)
   "ConnectionStrings": {
  "ProjetoTIConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=projetoti;Trusted_Connection=true"
}
```

(Startup.cs)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddDbContextPool<ProjectContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProjetoTIConnection")));
```

Comment: When you say "create the database" do you mean "add lots of tables to an existing empty database" or do you mean "create an new database in an empty server, and then add tables to the new database" ?

Comment: Are you speaking about [Entity Framework Core Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) for example? Could you please clarify that: what do you precisely mean by **Migration**?

Comment: Code-first , I do the specifications in the model and it automatically creates the database, only it only does the migration and does not create the database.

Comment: Did you run add-migration AND update-database? add-migration by itself just creates the file, update-database is the command that would generate the tables/database.

Comment: Yes, it runs normal everything just doesn't create the bank, which is the most important part .-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please **check the name of the server** where you want to create database.

In visual studio, you can open `View > SQL Server Object Explorer` in tool menu， then expend `SQL Server` node.

Here is my SQL Server Object Explorer structure:

[image]

So, the ConnectionStrings in appsettings.json should be :

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ProjetoTIConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=projetoti;Trusted_Connection=true"
   }
```

Then, after excuting the command of `add-migration` and `update-database`, the database named
`projetoti` will be created in the server which name is `(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb`.

So, please check your server name and ensure that the server name in the connection string is consistent with it.

Comment: Perhaps this will help someone in the future, but I had similar problems.  What fixed it in the end is that when copying the connection string from the server in VS2022, a "Data source" attribute appears in the string instead of "Server".  Replacing "Data source" with "Server" created the database.

Answer (score 0):

**You should also check the version of node you are using.**

**migration:run** stopped working when installed node v16.

But after I switched back to v18 it stated working fine.

I guess there is an issue with older node version support.